# HackerRank Coding Problem : Ways to sum to N using Natural Numbers up to K with repetitions allowed

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have coded recursive solutions for this problem

```
int NumberOfways(int total, int K, int start, int[] memo){
    
    if (total < 0) return 0;
    if (total == 0) return 1;
    if (memo[total] != -1 ) return memo[total];
    
    memo[total]=0;
    for(int i=start;i<=K;i++){
        memo[total] += R2NumberOfways(total-i,K,i,memo);
    }

    return memo[total];
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = 8;
    int K = 5;
    
    int[] memo = new int[N+1];
    for(int i=0; i<N+1;i++)
        memo[i] = -1;           

    System.out.println(NumberOfways(N,K,1,memo));
}
```

Answer for N=8, K=5 is 120, which is completely wrong. It should be 18.

But, following piece of code with global counter works and I am having difficult time understanding the difference. I am sure answer lies with the difference in recursion tree. But I am having difficulty visualizing the difference.

```
void NumberOfwaysWithGlobalCounter(int total, int K, int start){
    
    if (total < 0) return;
    if (total == 0) counter++;
    
    for(int i=start;i<=K;i++){
        NumberOfwaysWithGlobalCounter(total-i,K,i);
    }

    return;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = 8;
    int K = 5;

    counter=0;  
    NumberOfwaysWithGlobalCounter(N,K,1);
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: memo is 1D but needs to be 2D (total and start).

Comment: It's best to get the recursive solution working properly without memoization. Then add memoization. When done properly, the word `memo` should only appear at the beginning of the function, and the end. There should be no mention of `memo` in those three lines in the middle. Those lines should be exactly the same as they were without memoization.

Comment: Why the answer should 8? There are a lot more solutions than 8, unless I misunderstand the challenge.

Comment: Based on the comments, I’d say you need to provide a clearer specification of the problem being solved.

Comment: I believe all solutions of length n can be found uniquely by taking all solutions of length n-i which have a largest digit of at most i, and adding an extra i, for 1 <= i <= k.

Comment: I think there are 18 solutions for n=8, k=5. I'm omitting the plus signs for visual clarity, but imagine these digits being added together. 11111111, 1111112, 11122, 11222, 2222, 111113, 11123, 1223, 1133, 233, 11114, 1124, 224, 134, 44, 1115, 125, 35

Comment: I apologize it should be 18 and NOT 8. I have fixed the original post

Answer (score 1):

Make a table where one axis represents the sum (n), and the other axis represents the max digit among all solutions (so integers from 1 to k). The cells hold the count of all solutions that sum to n and have a max digit matching their column.

Then, to go from n-1 to n, set the (n, i) cell equal to the sum of the counts all solutions in the n-1 row with max_digits <= i. This represents taking these solutions and appending an i.

[image: Example pasted from a spreadsheet]

Comment: You only need to store the last k rows, and there are k columns, so this takes O(k^2) space. Each cell update requires up to k additions, and there are k cells to update each time we increment n, so O(n*k^2) time. We might be able to do better on running time by storing running row sums, but I don't have time to think about it now.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the DP table. I am trying to think in terms of recursion tree and trying to visualize how they are different between the correct and incorrect solution.